# Windows GDI Context - LoadImage

Tags: c++, windows, gdi

Using `LoadImage()` causes segmentation fault. Backtracing the stack I found the following function as called last:
`AlpcMaxAllowedMessageLength()`

This is the function I call:

```
status = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(STATUS_BMP), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,  LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION));
```

with STATUS_BMP loaded as a valid resource bitmap file.
Has someone encountered a similar problem about this function, or just have the solution to the matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is the fact that you are specifying that you want the image to be loaded from file by the LR_LOADFROMFILE flag, which means that the second parameter needs to be the string name of the standalone image file (this usually means on disk). You might try removing the LR_LOADFROMFILE flag and see if that fixes the issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx

When I have used this function, it has always been from a local file on disk.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying with a relative path. This was probably the real problem within this solution

Comment: So is this a local file or a resource that has been compiled into the module?

Comment: I tried with a resource, but then with the complete path of the bitmap. And it worked. Though, I'd like resource method to work, too.

Comment: I have spent many of hours trying to get resources to work with this function with no avail, so I'm not going to be able to help much with that issue. I have always just found it easier to write the resource to a temp file, and load it from that.

Comment: One thing that you might need to do is provide the handle to the module that contains the resource as the first argument when using the MAKEINTRESOURCE macro. Right now, if you just pass in NULL, it assumes you want one of the Windows OEM images not your own resource image.

Comment: My program has no modules right now. Therefore, I tried to use the instance of the .exe, also declared as argument of WinMain, unfortunately unsuccesfully. It still causes a segfault this way.

Comment: You can get a handle to the current process, which should be the one that holds the resource, with the GetCurrentProcess function. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

`MAKEINTRESOURCE` and `LR_LOADFROMFILE` are mutually exclusive.  Drop `LR_LOADFROMFILE`.

Comment: Now the function normally fails, instead of causing a violation access exception.

Comment: You need the HINSTANCE (aka HMODULE) of the executable or DLL that contains the resource.  I missed that in your original question.

Comment: I modified the function with the instance but it still fails

Comment: @Stencil: Then you need to provide more information for us to help you.  Show the part of the .rc file where the resource is defined.  Tell us the format of the .BMP file.  Can you see the resource in the binary with the resource editor in Visual Studio?

Comment: I found out the problem on the bitmap encoding. 32 bit bitmaps are not apparently supported and also cause the function to fail without setting a proper error code.

Comment: @Stencil:  LoadImage supports 32-bit bitmaps.  I've used it for that purpose many times.